# Is there any mechanism to lock a javascript array from getting updated automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am developing a javascript application which compares two arrays (second array is generated from primary array with references removed). The core idea of application is to compare the current array (primary) with secondary (last saved state) to identify the changes and act accordingly. The problem I am facing is sometimes the value of primary and secondary array becomes the same, I am playing with a huge javascript to manage html canvas. Thats why I am not posting the code as well...

Let me explain the situtaion:
Array X -> primary array, gets updated on mouse movement
Array Y -> last saved state, updated only when a mouse click occur

Once mouse click occur, the arrays will be the same and on mouse move 'X' will get updated and not 'Y'. On mouseup action, 'X' is compared with 'Y' to check all values are same, values change once mousup occur at top right of the screen; at that time 'Y' gets updated.

Sometimes is works; sometimes it does not.. I am wondering why!

I am thinking of a solution to lock 'Y' from editing, i.e. like a lock.

Comment: What you probably want is to clone your array.

Comment: I guess you are confused with `mousedown` and `click` event. That is why its working sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: You'll have to create a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) in order to get a decent answer to this question. Omitting the code because it's too big isn't an option. It's up to **you** to create a minimal replicating test case.

Comment: @dystroy i am copying arrays by clone, making use of prototype

Comment: @T.J.Crowdern I'll create a minimal version and post (let me check with Tushar's solution, if it does not solve, definitely i'll)

Comment: I am afraid why people are using down voting while it is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Actually you problem lay not in array itself. Objects (which are items of array) are copied *by reference* to another array. You need to *clone* them instead. There's no built-in method nor operator for that in javascript, but you could esaily google ready-for use solution.

If you have array of primitives and want to *protect* your code from occasional changes, then you may use `Object.freeze` whenever it is avaialable (it is not supported in all browsers). Debugging also may be useful, but `freeze` may help you identify exact place in code, where change is performed and should not.

Sorry, if I didn't answer your question - it looks a bit vague for me.

Comment: I'm using clone to copy arrays, by making use of  prototype as my array is a complex one

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real issue is that the update of Y is happening when you're not expecting it, and you need to debug the javascript to find out why. Put a breakpoint on the update code and see when it's called when it shouldn't and then you can fix the problem.

It may be that events are getting delayed and not happening when you expect if you're dealing with a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting confused with `mousedown` and `click` events.

I would recommend you to use the `click` event only. So here is the algo -

```
var primary, secondary;

var equal = function(a,b){
    //Code for comparing 2 arrays
    if(a.length !== b.length) return false
    for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] !== b[i]) return false
    }
    return true;
};
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
   primary = getData();//Some function which gets the data
});


window.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(equal(primary, secondary) === true){
        //Perform some action 
    }else{
        //Array has been update
        //Perform some action
    }
    //update secondary array
    secondary = primary.slice(0);
});
```